# netcdf c programming compilation

Tags: c, netcdf

I have a c program below which I am using to read a netcdf file:

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netcdf.h>


#define LAT_NAME "lat"
#define LON_NAME "lon"
#define TIME_NAME "time"
#define TAU_NAME "tau"
#define LAYER_NAME "depth"
#define U_NAME "water_u"
#define V_NAME "water_v" 
#define UNITS "units"
#define U_UNITS "m/s"
#define V_UNITS "m/s"
#define LAT_UNITS "degrees_north"
#define LON_UNITS "degrees_east"
#define MAX_ATT_LEN 80

float u_in[1][40][2001][4500], v_in[1][40][2001][4500];
char u_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN];
char v_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN];
char tau_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN];
char time_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN],layer_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN];
float lats_in[2001],lons_in[4500];
int time_in[1],tau_in[1],layer_in[40];
char lats_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN],lons_units_in[MAX_ATT_LEN];

int main(int argC,char **argV)
{

     int ncid, u_varid, v_varid, time_varid,layer_varid, tau_varid;
     int lats_varid,lons_varid;
     int ndims_in,nvars_in,ngatts_in,unlimdimid_in;
     int lats,lons; 
     int fd; 
     char dName[128],tName[128],fName[128],uFname[20],vFname[20]; 
     int i,j;
     FILE *fdu=NULL, *fdv=NULL;


    if (argC < 3)
    {

         printf("You did not run the program correctly. \n");   
         printf("-----------------------------------------\n"); 
         printf("Correct Useage: netcdf2txt <YYYYMMDD> <tau>\n");
         return(0);
     }  
     sscanf(argV[1],"%s",dName);
     sscanf(argV[2],"%s",tName);    
     sprintf(fName,"hycom_glb_911_%s00_t0%s_uv3z.nc",dName,tName);
     printf("fName is %s\n",fName);
     fd = nc_open(fName,NC_NOWRITE, &ncid);
     nc_inq(ncid, &ndims_in, &nvars_in, &ngatts_in, &unlimdimid_in);

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, TIME_NAME, &time_varid);
     nc_get_var_int(ncid,time_varid,&time_in[0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,time_varid, UNITS, time_units_in);
     printf("TIME_UNITS are %s\n",time_units_in);

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, TAU_NAME, &tau_varid);
     nc_get_var_int(ncid,tau_varid,&tau_in[0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,tau_varid, UNITS, tau_units_in);
     printf("TAU_UNITS are %s\n",tau_units_in);

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, LAYER_NAME, &layer_varid);
     nc_get_var_int(ncid,layer_varid,&layer_in[0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,layer_varid, UNITS, layer_units_in);
     printf("LAYER_UNITS are %s\n",layer_units_in);     
     printf("%d\n",layer_in[0]);

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, LAT_NAME, &lats_varid);
     nc_get_var_float(ncid,lats_varid,&lats_in[0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,lats_varid, UNITS, lats_units_in);
     printf("LAT_UNITS are %s\n",lats_units_in); 

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, LON_NAME, &lons_varid);
     nc_get_var_float(ncid,lons_varid,&lons_in[0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,lons_varid, UNITS, lons_units_in);
     printf("LONS_UNITS are %s\n",lons_units_in); 

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, U_NAME, &u_varid);
     nc_get_var_float(ncid,u_varid,&u_in[0][0][0][0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,u_varid, UNITS, u_units_in);
     printf("U_UNITS are %s\n",u_units_in);

     nc_inq_varid(ncid, V_NAME, &v_varid);
     nc_get_var_float(ncid,v_varid,&v_in[0][0][0][0]);
     nc_get_att_text(ncid,v_varid, UNITS, v_units_in);
     printf("V_UNITS are %s\n",v_units_in); enter code here
    }
 }
```

When I compile this program I get the error message:

```
netcdf2txt4.o: In function `main':
netcdf2txt4.c:(.text+0x221): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_X86_64_PC32    against symbol `layer_in' defined in 
.bss section in   netcdf2txt4.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [netcdf2txt4] Error 1
```

What does this error message mean?  I only get it when I add the section:

```c
 printf("%d\n",layer_in[0]);
```

into the code.  Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't post the very important gcc invocation line.

Comment: What gcc invocation line?

Comment: The Make file is : MKDIR=/bin/mkdir -p
RM=/bin/rm -rf
CP=/bin/cp

CC = g++
PROG = netcdf2txt4

SRCS = netcdf2txt4.c

OBJS= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

LIBPATH = -L/3psw/netcdf-3.6.0-p1/lib -L$(VRS_CVS)/build/lib

CFLAGS = $(COPTS) \
    -I/3psw/netcdf-3.6.0-p1/include \
    -I/usr/local/include \
    -I$(VRS_CVS)/src/include \
    $(LIBPATH)

PGSLIBS    = -lpq
SYSLIBS    = -lnsl -ldl -lm
LIBS = $(SYSLIBS) -lnetcdf 

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)  $(LIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) *~ *# *.o *.bak core tags TAGS .sb $(PROG)

Comment: Can you please append the content to the question? and, why `CC = g++`???? c is not c++.

Answer (score 0):

I saved Your code to file test.c

Running

```
gcc test.c
```

gives the same error message (among complaints of undefined functions), but simple

```
gcc test.c -L/opt/netcdf-4.3.2/lib -lnetcdf
```

Removes **all** error messages and I can start the program (without correct input I cannot check if everything is correct, but the usage message definitely is).

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile is looking for the netcdf.so file in directory netcdf-3.6.0-p1.

This is a very old version of netCDF. Probably you should install a newer version.

Look in your compile like for the options beginning with -L, that is where the compiler is going to look for the library files.